# How to change RichTextBox height to fit new font size in C#

Tags: c#, resize, richtextbox

My application allows the user to change the font, including font size, that is used in a `RichTextBox`.  The problem I'm having is that although the font size changes as expected, the height of the `RichTextBox` does not change accordingly.  The `RichTextBox` height needs to be maintained such that it is sufficient to show only one line of text.

When the font is changed the `RichTextBox` may not contain any text, so I'm currently trying to set the new height like so:

```
Font FONT = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 27F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
var height = TextRenderer.MeasureText("|", FONT).Height;
this.richTextBoxInput.Height = height;
```

Even though the code gets executed, the `RichTextBox` height doesn't change.  Here's how I have it initialized:

```
this.richTextBoxInput.Anchor = System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Top | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Bottom | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Left | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right;
this.richTextBoxInput.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
this.richTextBoxInput.BorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
this.richTextBoxInput.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 9F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
this.richTextBoxInput.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(50, 52);
this.richTextBoxInput.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(0);
this.richTextBoxInput.Name = "richTextBoxInput";
this.richTextBoxInput.ReadOnly = false;
this.richTextBoxInput.ScrollBars = System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBoxScrollBars.None;
this.richTextBoxInput.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(200, 20);
this.richTextBoxInput.TabIndex = 0;
this.richTextBoxInput.TabStop = false;
this.richTextBoxInput.Text = "<Input>";
```

Does anyone know how to make this work? I'm using .NET 4.5.

Comment: Your code changed the RTB height to 40 pixels on my machine.

Comment: Confirmed. Your code changes the RichTextBox height. What doesn't change it is the font because from that code it seems that you don't assign the newly created FONT

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a Custom RichTextBox or add the following to your own Custom Control.
The following code does not consider the Border Width, so I did add a fixed Offset (10).

```
    public class RichTextBoxCustom : RichTextBox
    {
        protected override void OnContentsResized(ContentsResizedEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnContentsResized(e);
            this.Height = e.NewRectangle.Height + 10;
        }
    }
```

Comment: If you are going through the trouble of inheriting the control, you wouldn't need to subscribe to its own events.  Just override the `OnContentsResized` method.

Comment: Yes, thank you. You are absolutely right. I did adjust my answer.